# Skyrim: Sleeping Safely in Solsteim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

In the Dragonborn DLC for Skyrim, you can travel to Solsteim.  If you sleep in any of the beds in Solsteim before Miraak is defeated, you wake up near one of the All-Maker Stones, having been hypnotized to work in your sleep like everyone else.

In an un-modded game, this is little more than an annoyance.  However, I am using the Realistic Needs & Diseases, so I am required to sleep periodically.  So, that makes the problem more annoying.  On top of that, I am also using the Frostfall mod, which means that this issue becomes potentially dangerous to my character, rather than merely annoying.

Is there any mod or method to disable this "feature", or should I just turn off RN&D and Frostfall when I'm in Solsteim?

Comment: Don't use the mod?  Seems like the simplest option.

Comment: In reality sleeping regularly adds nothing to gameplay other than giving you a maintenance chore.  I played Fallout New Vegas "hardcore" mode and that mode is more of an annoyance than anything.

Comment: @Nelson Some people prefer hardcore-roleplaying over normal roleplaying. I'm not one of those, but I've met people who were just walking in games like witcher because it seemed to them unrealistic that a character runs the entire time. If OP is one of those, i doubt that he want to disable this mod.

Comment: The "teleport when sleeping" is obviously not suppose to outright kill you.  The combination of mods are killing the player whenever he sleeps in Solsteim, so he might consider turning them off regardless of his role-playing goals.

Comment: This sounds like a really fun challenge. I'd consider this an intended feature.

Answer (score 4):

The sleepwalking effect in Dragonborn ends when the stones are cleansed using the Bend Will shout. This of course requires working through the main quest at least far enough to get the shout, or using console commands to force the quests to complete neither of which you probably want.

Turning off the fatigue feature of RND or setting the rate to a very low number to allow more time between sleep periods is probably the best approach. Setting the fatigue rate to 1 means it takes 5 days before you are Very Tired. This allows you complete short adventures on Solstheim and return by boat to Skyrim to sleep. You could justify this with roleplaying by drinking herbal tea, although there is no in-game caffeine effect.

Or just leave the mod on the default setting and sleep normally. Aside from the teleportation effect when sleeping, there's no real downside. You just may have to adapt your current adventure goal to whatever your current location is, rather than completing adventures in some kind of geographical order.

Comment: I think the issue is the combination of the Frostfall mod.  This gives you hypothermia and can kill you if you sleep outside.  I believe the issue is this:  Sleep -> Teleport -> Hypothermia (since you'll always be teleported outside).

Comment: Yeah, frostfall is more the issue here.

Comment: There are ways of dealing with that as well. Frostfall adds some spells that improve survival (Foxskin, Wolfskin, and Bearskin, IIRC,) which you cold cast before going to sleep. I haven't tested this, because I haven't visited Solstheim in my Frostfall/RND modded play through. Perhaps I'll do some testing and update my answer.

Comment: OK, this may take a while, because it's the first time I've played Skyrim since upgrading to Windows 10. MCM menus aren't displaying information, and I suspect that scripting is messed up... Not getting any Frostfall or RND messages at all. Once I fix that, I'll test some possible solutions.